# UnauthorizedAccessException when saving file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a website for my final year project using visual studio 2013 asp.net and C#

It is an online CV creator so the user enters their details and presses submit and a PDF is generated (iTextSharp).

The problem is that it runs fine from Visual Studio but when I publish it online, it gives me an error which can be found below.

> Access to the path 'C:\cv.pdf' is denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\cv.pdf' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

```
Stack Trace: 
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\cv.pdf' is denied.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +217
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1305
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +60
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) +55
   CV.createpdf() +86
   CV.submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +364
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9753402
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +196
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

myonlinecvcreator.azurewebsites.net

I'm really starting to get worried as I need to have it done by saturday as it is my final year project and obviously, I need to pass :)

Comment: It seems unlikely to be a good idea for a web site to have *write* access to the root of the c drive. Store your file somewhere else.

Comment: You are saving that CV under C: drive directly! Consider putting a separate folder somewhere and give permission (right click on that folder, under security) to that folder to IUSR_<yourMachineName>

Comment: Simply, you don't have rights to write at `"C:\"`. Change destination where you save your file, create path using `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: Where is best to store it then?

Comment: @Huza91 at your site directory. Create folder like "temp" and write there.

Comment: Fyodor, would you be able to show me how to do that?? Also guys, i just want to say how grateful i am for all your help

Comment: See here: [Create a file in a folder of an Azure-hosted website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854424/create-a-file-in-a-folder-of-an-azure-hosted-website)

Comment: Awesome. I'm going to try that tomorrow. If i have anymore issues, could i contact you?

Comment: @Huza91 You could always create questions here, at SO if you will have any. Don't get offended but I suggest you to google first, because such problems were discussed many times and solution can be easily found. Also, format your questions more neatly in order to get help really ASAP, people usually ignore bad formatted questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is a directory created with your web application called `App_Data`. I would suggest you create the file there:

```
string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/cv.PDF");
```